# how to exit or close from a trade during specific period of time. Pine script

Tags: pine-script

I need to insert an input time for exit or close a trade.
For example, after inserting an order I would like to exit or close the trade after a specific time.
I would like an option to choose between 3 and 15 minutes.
please, insert as default value 3 minutes of time expiration for each trade.

I tried this Pine script code, and I would like put after strategy.entry a exit/close after 3 minutes.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © djowkim

//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

longCondition = ta.crossover(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)
    // insert here or in a better place a exit or close from trader after 3 minutes.

shortCondition = ta.crossunder(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)
    // please insert here or in a better place a exit or close from trader after 3 minutes.
belowbar,   color =  color.blue)
```

Comment: On what timeframe are you going to be running this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `strategy.opentrades.entry_time` to get the entry time in UNIX format. Then calculate the difference between current time and entry time and convert it to minutes.

Here is an example:

```
exit_time = input.int(10, "Exit time")

entry_time = strategy.opentrades.entry_time(strategy.opentrades - 1)
time_since_entry_in_min = (time - entry_time) / 60000

if (time_since_entry_in_min >= exit_time)
    strategy.close("Long")
```

**Note:** In order for this to work, your chart's timeframe must be lower than your timeout value. And ideally, the timeout value should be a multiple of your chart's timeframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
if strategy.opentrades > 0
    if (time - strategy.opentrades.entry_time(strategy.opentrades - 1)) > 3 * 60 * 1000 // Test if it is more than 3 minutes since the trade is open
        strategy.close_all()
```

For this to work, you must use a 3 minutes timeframe or less on your chart, as your pinescript code is run on each bar close.